# How can I upload a generated image via FTP without saving it locally

Tags: php, image, ftp

I have successfully overlaid a .png file atop a .jpg file. The problem is, I need to FTP this file to another server, preferably without ever saving it locally. I've looked into temp files with PHP, but can't make sense of it.

Specifically, I'm tossing some variables to a function. The function finds the right path for the PNG file from the database, lays it over the JPEG file from the path given. The combined image needs uploaded to an off-site server... this is where my coding experience fails me. If I'm writing this new image to a temp file, how to I pass its path back to be uploaded, rather than the image itself.

```
    $overlayFilePath = '../overlays/'.$row["Overlay1"];

    $png = imagecreatefrompng($overlayFilePath);
    $jpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg($local_file);

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($local_file);
    list($newwidth, $newheight) = getimagesize($overlayFilePath);
    $out = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($out, $jpeg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($out, $png, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $newwidth, $newheight);
    $combinedImage = imagejpeg($out, NULL, 100);
    imagedestroy($out);

    return $combinedImage; // this is the issue. I need to return an address to the image, but I do not want to have thousands of images being saved locally on this server.

    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: does it have to be ftp? do you have any control over the remote server

Comment: I do. The way so many systems are setup, I'd prefer FTP; but what did you have in mind? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: OK. I decided to just use a single file locally that gets wrote over and over. Not exactly HOW I was wanting to do it, but is did accomplish WHAT I was wanting to do. Thanks guys.

Comment: $this->temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'tempImg');

...


$local_file = $this->temp;
$outfile = '//PATH/e/to/local/file/jpeg.jpg';

$copy = copy($local_file, $outfile);